# Fixing layout of wordpress site`

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I'm facing some issues with the width of my website which is [Click here](http://www.vky.co.in)

I want to make it full width website , it's not showing correctly from the right side, you can have a look at URL for better understanding about my problem.

Thanks !

Comment: please add some code to your question not just a link to your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all these margin properties from your CSS file/Media Queries

```
#top{
   margin: 0 -1.618em;
} 

only screen and (min-width: 768px){
   #top{
      margin: 0 -3.631em;
   }

   .footer-wrap{
      margin: 0 -3.631em;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you So much ! Your code works perfectly.